# Need to extract values from a XML file

Tags: php, xml

I have a XML file, and the layout is such

```
<author>
   <name></name>
   <iso></iso>
   <price></price>

</author>
```

I know how it loops.  I want to know how I can extract the value of

```
<name>
```

Thanks
Jean

[edit]

my apologies, if in the

```
 <author>
          <name>
            <first_name></first_name>
            <last_name></lastname>
          </name>
  </author>
```

I want to extract first_name

Comment: Try PHP's inbuilt XML parser. http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [simplexml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) or similar:

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<author>
    <name>
        <first_name>John</first_name>
        <last_name>Smith</last_name>
    </name>
</author>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

var_dump($xml);
?>
```

Will output something like this:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["name"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) {
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(4) "John"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(5) "Smith"
  }
}
```

And you can access the name like this:

```
echo $xml->name->first_name; // outputs 'John'
echo $xml->name->last_name; // outputs 'Smith'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

**Edit:** I see. That wasn't showing up before. Try this:

```
$xml = simple_xml_load_string([your XML string])
echo $xml->name;
```

Does that work?

Comment: I am using simplexml, but i want to extract the value of <name>

Comment: @Jean: This is perfectly described in the SimpleXML documentation (http://no.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Comment: Sorry, My question was wrongly put up, pls check the question